# What IFC versions are supported in Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are working on an integration of an external software with Autodesk Forge. Following openBIM, we want to focus on model data in IFC format. Question is (and I was not able to find this answer online) which IFC versions are supported in the Forge ecosystem? Would one have to be careful with using e.g. only IFC 2x3 or is IFC 4 Add4 also supported? The documentation at https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/ only generally mentions the IFC support, but no versions ... which would be a necessary information IMHO, as the format is still in active development.

Comment: Let me check with our MD Team so I can get you the correct information in regard to the IFC versions supported by Forge.

Comment: Hi @JaimeRosales - Thanks for your effort, looking forward hearing back from you!

Comment: @JaimeRosales - did you already hear back from your colleagues? Would be great to hear some quick feedback on this! Thanks - Robert

Answer (score 0):

(Just happened to see this thread)

As I know, there is no  IFC 4 Add4, but  IFC 4 Add2. See https://technical.buildingsmart.org/standards/ifc/ifc-schema-specifications/

Forge Model Derivative API currently has three IFC conversion methods: legacy, modern, and v3, which are the same as [Navisworks IFC readers](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/navisworks-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2023/ENU/Navisworks/files/GUID-E1CD4663-D460-4EA5-ABEC-FD24885BA3A6-htm.html).

- The legacy conversion method is under maintenance mode and doesn't fully support IFC4. So, it won't get updates anymore. For better IFC4 support, please use modern or v3 instead.
- The modern conversion method is based on Revit technics. Currently, Revit supports IFC4 and IFC2x3. Its main features of exporting/importing IFC are provided by our open-source project [Autodesk/revit-ifc](https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/releases). Model Derivative API uses Revit to export IFC from RVT files so that the supported IFC version will be the same as [Autodesk/revit-ifc](https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/releases) provided.
- The v3 conversion method is based on the modern one but has some improvements (e.g. using file native distance units, not always feet)

**Note.** IFC4.x is not yet supported. For more details, please check out:

- https://blogs.autodesk.com/revit/2022/02/09/now-available-revit-ifc-manual-version-2-0/ (Point Releases (4.x) already in the pipeline, including enhancements and new classes for infrastructure including bridges, railways, roads, ports, and waterways.)
- https://technical.buildingsmart.org/standards/ifc/ifc-schema-specifications/ (BuildingSmart withdrew IFC4x1 and IFC4x2, and they are developing IFC4x3)
- https://github.com/Autodesk/revit-ifc/releases/tag/IFC_v22.3.0.0 (Added additional generic support for IFC4.x files for 2022.1)

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/export-ifc-rvt-using-model-derivative-api